# How to differentiate between two Date Time in C language -Loadrunner Web?

Tags: c, difference, loadrunner, mktime

I am trying to find differentiation between two date(i.e. 14:49:41 and 15:50:42) using below code:

```
    Action()
{
    struct tm { 
    int tm_sec; 
    int tm_min; 
    int tm_hour; 
  }; 

  int rc; // return code
  struct tm date1;
  struct tm date2;
  long time_difference; // the number of time ticks (seconds) that separate date1 and date2.
  int hours, minutes, seconds;

  // Save example dates to a parameter. 
  // capture these values using web_reg_save_param or similar.
  // date format: hh:mm:ss
  lr_save_string("14:49:41", "Param_Date1");
  lr_save_string("15:50:42", "Param_Date2");

  // Read the values from the string into the date variables
  rc = sscanf(lr_eval_string("{Param_Date1}"), "%d:%d:%d",&date1.tm_hour, &date1.tm_min, &date1.tm_sec);


  // Repeat the above steps for Date2
  rc = sscanf(lr_eval_string("{Param_Date2}"), "%d:%d:%d", &date2.tm_hour, &date2.tm_min, &date2.tm_sec);




  time_difference = mktime(&date2) - mktime(&date1);
  lr_output_message("Total number of seconds difference: %d", time_difference);

  // Calculate time difference in  hours, minutes and seconds.

  hours = time_difference/3600;
  time_difference = time_difference - (hours * 3600);
  minutes = time_difference/60;
  time_difference = time_difference - (minutes * 60);
  seconds = time_difference;
  lr_output_message("Hours: %d, Minutes: %d, Seconds: %d", hours, minutes, seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output should return : Hours: 1, Minutes: 1, Seconds: 1
But output returns : Hours: 0, Minutes: 0, Seconds: 0

Please help me fix this problem. Or Else any other alternative achieve it?

Comment: In both `date1` and `date2`, you need to set `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, and `tm_day` to valid values, and also set `tm_isdst` to -1.

Comment: Also you need to `#include <time.h>`, and get rid of your own definition of `struct tm`.

Answer (score 0):

hours, minutes and seconds should not be declared as Integers as you are dividing the value by 3600. If you declare them as floating point numbers it may work. Other than that everything looks good

Comment: No, it must be integer division, not floating point. Otherwise 90 minutes would become 1.5 hours 0 minutes instead of 1 hour 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two times in seconds is easy to compute:

```
int secs1 = ((time1.hour * 60) + time1.min) * 60 + time1.sec;
int secs1 = ((time2.hour * 60) + time2.min) * 60 + time2.sec;
int sec_dif = secs1 - secs2;
```

Or this way:

```
int sec_dif =
    ((time1.hour - time2.hour) * 60 + (time1.min - time2.min)) * 60 + (time1.min - time2.min);

int min_dif = sec_dif / 60;
int hour_dif = sec_dif / (60 * 60);
```

No need to bother with converting the times into `time_t` types.